# Problem with property inherited from parent entity

Tags: core-data, entity, parent

I'm trying to keep traveling route in core data and here is my data model. I have entity **Coordinate** keeping latitude and longitude in double, then I created **Locatable** entity and make relation between these two entities.

```
Coordinate <-> Locatable
```

then I have **POI** entity inherited **Locatable** these **POI** representing my route.
finally I have **Destination** entity inherited **POI** using as my destination point

```
Coordinate <-> Locatable
                   |
                   V
                  POI
                   |
                   V
               Destination
```

My **Route** class have points as one-to-many relation with these **POI** and destination as one-to-one with **Destination**.
Problem occur when I try to get my **POI** collection for create route with MKPolylineView, when I call route.points I also get my destination point with those POI. I know core data create big Locatable for both POI and Destination, but this behavior isn't logically right my destination point shouldn't show up with points. Is this right behavior or I missing something.

Quite complicated to explain if I miss some important information please tell me.

**Updated for more clarify**

I have Route entity with one-to-one with Destination as destination and one-to-many with POI as points(which I using as my traveling path)

When I add destination

```
route.destination = destination_obj
```

it also show up in

```
route.points
```

which doesn't right because these two property serve two different purpose (one for making traveling path, another for pre calculate some data). Is this behavior have any document or explanation ?

**Added small data model and code sample so every one can reproduce this**
Make 3 entity

```
Family 
- int generation
- parents as to-may relation to Parent and family as inverse
- child as to-one relation to Child and family as inverse
Parent
- String name
- family to-one relation to Family
Child : Parent
```

Here is my code

```
Family *fam;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Family" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *meters = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

if ([meters count] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"found");
    fam = [meters lastObject];
    fam.generation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[fam.generation intValue] + 1];
} else {
    NSLog(@"new");
    fam = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fam.generation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    [self saveContext];
};
NSLog(@"There are %d paren", [fam.parents count]);
for (Parent *p in fam.parents) {
    NSLog(@"name : %@", p.name);
}
Child *child;
if (!fam.child) {
    child = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:
             [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext] name]
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    fam.child = child;
}
fam.child.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"child number %d", [fam.generation intValue]];
NSLog(@"There are %d parent after adding one child", [fam.parents count]);

Parent *parent = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:
                  [[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext] name]
                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
parent.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"parent number %d", [fam.generation intValue]];
[fam addParentsObject:parent];

NSLog(@"There are  %d parent after add parent", [fam.parents count]);
for (Parent *p in fam.parents) {
    NSLog(@"name : %@", p.name);
}

[self saveContext];
```

in short I create family and add one child and one parent to this family and print out some output
in the first run I got this result

```
2011-08-27 19:06:28.271 child[2015:207] new
2011-08-27 19:06:28.276 child[2015:207] There are 0 paren
2011-08-27 19:06:28.278 child[2015:207] There are 0 parent after adding one child
2011-08-27 19:06:28.279 child[2015:207] There are  1 parent after add parent
2011-08-27 19:06:28.280 child[2015:207] name : parent number 1
```

which is what I expected, then I rerun the app again and this what the weird thing occur

```
2011-08-27 19:08:12.383 child[2035:207] found
2011-08-27 19:08:12.386 child[2035:207] There are 2 paren
2011-08-27 19:08:12.387 child[2035:207] name : parent number 1
2011-08-27 19:08:12.388 child[2035:207] name : child number 1
2011-08-27 19:08:12.389 child[2035:207] There are 2 parent after adding one child
2011-08-27 19:08:12.390 child[2035:207] There are  3 parent after add parent
2011-08-27 19:08:12.390 child[2035:207] name : parent number 1
2011-08-27 19:08:12.391 child[2035:207] name : parent number 2
2011-08-27 19:08:12.391 child[2035:207] name : child number 2
```

child entity is included in parents property. This is some kind of my misconception or this is a bug on SDK ?

Comment: What is **foo**? A **Locatable**?

Comment: I have changed foo to route for more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is too complicated. Also, you set up your relationships a bit like *sub-classes*. But relationships and sub-classes are completely different concepts, and I think you might be mixing them up.

Here is what I propose:

Have an entity **Location**, with attributes **latitude**, **longitude** and **name**. Set **latitude** and **longitude** as non-optional, but **name** as optional. Now you have all the basic building blocks you need.

In your code you can define objects such as *POI of type **Location**, *destination of type **Location** and *startPoint of type **Location**. You can use the coordinates to calculate the shortest route for example. By setting the **name** you can make any **Location** into a POI. If you want names for non-POIs, create a boolean attribute **isPOI**.

Now, if you want to store specific travel routes, you can introduce an entity **Route**, with attributes like **name**, **date** etc. and a one-to-many relationship to **Location**. Note that you can not put the many **Locations** in any particular order with this scheme. However, what you could do is include two more one-to-one relationships to **Location**, one called **startLocation** and one **destination**.

If you really need a more complex description of itineraries in your core data model, you probably need another entity. You could call it **TravelPoints** with a many-to-one relationship to **Route**, a one-to-one relationship to **Location** and attributes like **arrivalDate**, **timeStayed** or **departureDate**, **sequentialNumber** (to indicated the order in **Route**), etc.

With this setup you should be able to go far with your project.

Comment: How sub class in core data different from real sub class ? The problem is when I set one property (Destination) it got mixed up with another one (POI) which it shouldn't. Do you have any document or reference on this situation, Thank you.

Comment: A real subclass inherits properties from its superclass and extends these or overrides the default ones. When you define a Location as a Route's destination and that Location is also a POI you just a have additional information which you can use or not. So I do not see any problem. --  In general you want to avoid too many "subclass-like" one-to-one relationships if you can encapsulate that information in just one entity.

Comment: The problem about performance is one thing, but now I got problem on property mixed up (calling route.points also return destination).

Comment: Then don't put your destination into route.points, put it into route.destination. Performance should be better with less entities.

Comment: Yes I put destination by route.destination = destination, but when I called route.points, destination also show up there. This confusing me so much.

Comment: Check again how you set up points. Make sure your destination is not in there. (Please consider accepting my answer in the meantime.)

Comment: I checked it and nothing wrong. Now try to repro this on smaller entity model to see if the problem persist and will update it shortly